# Passing values to the Controller with BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to pass **form values** to my Controller **plus a Model** that I am using.

Would the below syntax be correct when posting to the Controller?

HTML

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GeneratePDF", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult GeneratePDF(FormCollection values, ViewModelTemplate_Guarantors tg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not combine both into a specific ViewModel? Something like

```
public GeneratePDFModel
{
    public string FormCollectionValueFoo {get;set;}
    public string FormCollectionValueBar {get;set;}
    ViewModelTemplate_Guarantors OtherModel {get;set;}
}
```

Or derive from `ViewModelTemplate_Guarantors`?

```
public GeneratePDFModel : ViewModelTemplate_Guarantors
{
    public string FormCollectionValueFoo {get;set;}
    public string FormCollectionValueBar {get;set;}
}
```

That way everything is strongly typed.